# IntentService and Activity Lifecycle

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I followed [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html) on how to reverse geocode in Android, but I can't understand how this `IntentService` will deal nicely with the `Activity` lifecycle. I am following [this code sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationAddress/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationaddress/MainActivity.java).

As far as I understand, the `Activity` will hold an instance of the `AddressResultReceiver`, named `mResultReceiver`. When the `IntentService` get's back the reverse-geocoded address, it will call `mReceiver.send(resultCode, bundle)` from the `mResultReceiver` instace, which will then update the UI, inside the `Activity`.

My question is how will this play along with the `Activity` lifecycle. Lets assume the `Activity` started the `IntentService` and then, by some reason, it was destroyed (like, the user rotated the screen). Later, when the `IntentService` receives the address back from Google Maps, it will call the `mResultReceiver` it recevied from the original `Activity`, that is right now destroyed (or it could have been created again, but still, it will be a new instance anyway).

Since the `mResultReceiver` is created when the `Activity` is created, and it isn't saved on any `Bundle` for later retrieval, when the `IntentService` completes and calls the original `mResultReceiver`, what would happen?

- Will the `mResultReceiver` call be automagically forwarded to a new instance of the `Activity`, like nothing happend and all work as expected?
- Will `mResultReceiver` be Garbage Collected with the destroyed `Activity`, and the `IntentService` will throw an exception when it tries to use the destroyed class?
- Will `mResultReceiver` prevent the original `Activity` from being garbage collected, specially because the `IntentService`is still holding a reference to the `mResultReceiver` object. And when the `IntentService` calls `mReceiver.send(resultCode, bundle)` it will make no difference on the actual `Activity` on screen, or throw an exception for trying to update already destroyed UI Widgets?
- Is this google example flawed? What's the right way to do it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the google example is flawed. The sample will result in a memory leak if activity is destroyed. A better approach would be using a local broadcast receiver or an Event Bus or RxJava/RxAndroid
[Issue is already reported here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/issues/60)